# My mysql-function will not work?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a problem making a stored mysql function. First I tried to make it quite easy following the official tutorial: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

```
create function bestalldavaror_7()
RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
RETURN select sum(mangd) from bestalln where artikel_id = 7;
```

The select-query works just fine by itself and the "mangd" is an int(11) value (so is everything in that table). So why does this generate an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select sum(mangd) from bestalln where artikel_id = 7' at line 3

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So make this change:

```
create function bestalldavaror_7()
RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
RETURN (select sum(mangd) from bestalln where artikel_id = 7);
```

and it should work.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me back "#1548 - Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted" which is strange. Remake the table maybe?

Comment: I am currently using a phpmyadmin interface:

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Serverversion: 5.5.11-log
Protocolversion: 10
User: username@localhost
MySQL char-encoding: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

I am running archlinux

Comment: Hmm... you might want to run `mysql_upgrade` to check/repair tables.

Comment: I think I need to update the whole system. Anyway, thank you I dont actually need to store it in the database right now. Just wanted to make sure that the syntax were right.